# Calculate Transaction Gas Fee

Tags: c#, blockchain, ethereum, nethereum

**I am trying to find out the fee for a normal transaction on the Ethereum network !!**

```
//Get Network Gas Price For singl unit
var GasPrice= await web3.Eth.GasPrice.SendRequestAsync();

//Assuming the number of major units is 21000
var TransactionLimit = new HexBigInteger(21000).Value;

var TransactionFee = GasPrice.Value * TransactionLimit;
```

- Are the steps taken correct?
- And what is the refund value in this case, is it Wei or Gwei or what!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your calculation is correct, but I recommend reading [Ethereum: Gas and Fees](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/gas/), which explains the cases before and after the Ethereum London upgrade.

Note that in your case, `TransactionLimit` is not how many gas units you'll actually use, but the upper limit after which your transaction won't be executed anymore. The difference between the actually burnt gas units and the limit is refunded.

All the values are in Wei.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look at the ethereum blog, I once read that the price of a normal transaction on the network costs 21000 (wei according to your statement) can this limit change to more than this!!?